# Bad state: add(LoadFavoriteMovieEvent) was called without a registered event handler. Error

Tags: flutter, dart, bloc, flutter-bloc

The codes in my bloc file you see below. But I get an error like : **"Bad state: add(LoadFavoriteMovieEvent) was called without a registered event handler. Make sure to register a handler via on((event, emit) {...})"**. How can I fix this error I received? I would be very happy if you help me.

```
class FavoriteBloc extends Bloc<FavoriteEvent, FavoriteState> {
  final SaveMovie saveMovie;
  final GetFavoriteMovies getFavoriteMovies;
  final DeleteFavoriteMovie deleteFavoriteMovie;
  final CheckIfFavoriteMovie checkIfFavoriteMovie;

  FavoriteBloc({
    required this.saveMovie,
    required this.getFavoriteMovies,
    required this.deleteFavoriteMovie,
    required this.checkIfFavoriteMovie,
  }) : super(FavoriteInitial());

  @override
  Stream<FavoriteState> mapEventToState(
    FavoriteEvent event,
  ) async* {
    if (event is ToggleFavoriteMovieEvent) {
      if (event.isFavorite) {
        await deleteFavoriteMovie(
          MovieParams(event.movieEntity.id),
        );
      } else {
        await saveMovie(event.movieEntity);
      }
      final response = await checkIfFavoriteMovie(
        MovieParams(event.movieEntity.id),
      );
      yield response.fold(
        (l) => FavoriteMoviesError(),
        (r) => IsFavoriteMovie(r),
      );
    } else if (event is LoadFavoriteMovieEvent) {
      yield* _fetchLoadFavoriteMovies();
    } else if (event is DeleteFavoriteMovieEvent) {
      await deleteFavoriteMovie(
        MovieParams(event.movieId),
      );
      yield* _fetchLoadFavoriteMovies();
    } else if (event is CheckIfFavoriteMovieEvent) {
      final response = await checkIfFavoriteMovie(
        MovieParams(event.movieId),
      );
      yield response.fold(
        (l) => FavoriteMoviesError(),
        (r) => IsFavoriteMovie(r),
      );
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

It look like you are trying to use bloc version more or equal then v8.0.0 with old approach. mapEventToState(..) is depricated. more info [here](https://bloclibrary.dev/#/migration?id=packagebloc-1). Now you code will look something like this:

```
class FavoriteBloc extends Bloc<FavoriteEvent, FavoriteState> {
  final SaveMovie saveMovie;
  final GetFavoriteMovies getFavoriteMovies;
  final DeleteFavoriteMovie deleteFavoriteMovie;
  final CheckIfFavoriteMovie checkIfFavoriteMovie;

  FavoriteBloc({
    required this.saveMovie,
    required this.getFavoriteMovies,
    required this.deleteFavoriteMovie,
    required this.checkIfFavoriteMovie,
  }) : super(FavoriteInitial()) {
    on<ToggleFavoriteMovieEvent>(_onToggleFavoriteMovieEvent);
    on<LoadFavoriteMovieEvent>(_onLoadFavoriteMovieEvent);
    on<DeleteFavoriteMovieEvent>(_onDeleteFavoriteMovieEvent);
    on<CheckIfFavoriteMovieEvent>(_onCheckIfFavoriteMovieEvent);
  }

  Future<void> _onToggleFavoriteMovieEvent(ToggleFavoriteMovieEvent event, Emitter<FavoriteState> emit) async {
    if (event.isFavorite) {
      await deleteFavoriteMovie(
        MovieParams(event.movieEntity.id),
      );
    } else {
      await saveMovie(event.movieEntity);
    }
    final response = await checkIfFavoriteMovie(
      MovieParams(event.movieEntity.id),
    );
    emit(
      response.fold(
        (l) => FavoriteMoviesError(),
        (r) => IsFavoriteMovie(r),
      ),
    );
  }
  // All other event handlers here. 
}
```

Comment: He gave me the same code when I asked for chat gpt but it didn't work

Comment: what exactly is not working? try ask again with other peace of code