# Make sure to register a handler via on<LoadFavoriteMovieEvent>((event, emit) {...}). Error

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-bloc

The codes below are the codes I wrote. But I get an error like this. The error I get is :

***" Bad state: add(LoadFavoriteMovieEvent) was called without a registered event handler. Make sure to register a handler via on((event, emit) {...}). "***

```
class FavoriteBloc extends Bloc<FavoriteEvent, FavoriteState> {
  final SaveMovie saveMovie;
  final GetFavoriteMovies getFavoriteMovies;
  final DeleteFavoriteMovie deleteFavoriteMovie;
  final CheckIfFavoriteMovie checkIfFavoriteMovie;

  FavoriteBloc({
    required this.saveMovie,
    required this.getFavoriteMovies,
    required this.deleteFavoriteMovie,
    required this.checkIfFavoriteMovie,
  }) : super(FavoriteInitial()) {
    on<ToggleFavoriteMovieEvent>((event, emit) async {
      if (event.isFavorite) {
        await deleteFavoriteMovie(
          MovieParams(event.movieEntity.id),
        );
      } else {
        await saveMovie(event.movieEntity);
      }
      final response = await checkIfFavoriteMovie(
        MovieParams(event.movieEntity.id),
      );
      emit(response.fold(
        (l) => FavoriteMoviesError(),
        (r) => IsFavoriteMovie(r),
      ));
    });

    on<CheckIfFavoriteMovieEvent>((event, emit) async {
      final response = await checkIfFavoriteMovie(
        MovieParams(event.movieId),
      );
      emit(response.fold(
        (l) => FavoriteMoviesError(),
        (r) => IsFavoriteMovie(r),
      ));
    });
  }

  @override
  Stream<FavoriteState> mapEventToState(
    FavoriteEvent event,
  ) async* {
    if (event is LoadFavoriteMovieEvent) {
      yield* _fetchLoadFavoriteMovies();
    } else if (event is DeleteFavoriteMovieEvent) {
      await deleteFavoriteMovie(
        MovieParams(event.movieId),
      );
      yield* _fetchLoadFavoriteMovies();
    }
  }

  Stream<FavoriteState> _fetchLoadFavoriteMovies() async* {
    final Either<AppError, List<MovieEntity>> response =
        await getFavoriteMovies(
      NoParams(),
    );

    yield response.fold(
      (l) => FavoriteMoviesError(),
      (r) => FavoriteMoviesLoaded(r),
    );
  }
}
```

I would be very grateful if you can help me what is the solution to this error. Thanks in advance to everyone who helps.

Comment: on event missing for LoadFavoriteMovieEvent in bloc and you called add(LoadFavoriteMovieEvent) without on event . Just add on<LoadFavoriteMovieEvent> in bloc your  problem will be fixed.

Comment: Can you show me how to do it by modifying the code?

Comment: this answer your question
https://stackoverflow.com/a/77759451/5243472 


you should put a little effort into figuring it out on your own